# import bean and call method using jstl in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have the following code in a jsp and want to translate it to jstl.
If i create a servlet and save the content of dateDay in the session and pass to a jsp it works but i want everything to be done in the jsp i.e importing the bean and getting the dateDay printed, all in jstl.

```
<jsp:useBean id="dj" class="mypack.DatatextFormat"/>

<%
dj.setDateShort(new java.util.Date());
String dateDay=dj.getDateShort();
%>
My formatted date is: <%= dateDay%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're OK with instantiating the *dateShort* property in the default constructor of your bean, and with using EL, you can do something like

```
<jsp:useBean id="dj" class="mypack.DatatextFormat" scope="session"/>
<c:set var="dateDay"  value="${dj.date}"/>
<c:out value="${dateDay}"/>
```

or simply output like

```
${dj.date}
```

**update after comment**

```
<jsp:useBean id="today" class="java.util.Date" scope="page" />
<jsp:useBean id="dj" class="mypack.DatatextFormat" scope="session">
  <jsp:setProperty name="dj" property="shortDate" value="${today}"/>
</jsp:useBean>
<c:set var="dateDay"  value="${dj.shortDate}"/>
<c:out value="${dateDay}"/>
```

Comment: How do i instantiate the dateShort property in jstl? I do not know how to translate this: dj.setDateShort(new java.util.Date());?

Comment: I've edited the question, you cannot instantiate java.util.Date and set it to dateShort by using JSTL only, what you see in the edit, is the closest that you can get, hope it helps